# Save values to an array on checkbox inside ng-repeat in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a scenario in which I have to put values in array when the checkbox is checked in ng-repeat.

```
<li ng-repeat="player in team.players">
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-3 m-t-xs">
       <input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.newEvent.players[$index].selected" ng-change="vm.selectPlayer($index, player)"> {{player.name}}
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-5 m-t-xs">
        <label for="">
         <input type="radio" name="{{player.id}}" ng-change="vm.disSelectPlayer($index, player)" ng-model="vm.newEvent.players[$index].casuality.type" value="injured"> Injured
        </label>
        <label for="">
         <input type="radio" name="{{player.id}}" ng-change="vm.disSelectPlayer($index, player)" ng-model="vm.newEvent.players[$index].casuality.type" value="sick"> Sick
        </label>
        <label for="">
         <input type="radio" name="{{player.id}}" ng-change="vm.disSelectPlayer($index, player)" ng-model="vm.newEvent.players[$index].casuality.type" value="other"> Other
        </label>
     </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

This is how it looks now in browser.

[image]

The issue is that when I clicked any of the player name in **FC Barcelona Accordion** it also selects the same indexed player from **FC Bayern Munich Accordion**, What I want is to keep all players separate form each-other.
Am i missing something in the binding ??

Comment: I think those checkbox have same names

Comment: Yeah thats the problem I want solution for.

Comment: create name using some id or counter.

Comment: There will be two indexes , one corresponding to your accordion(football clubs) and one corresponding to your football players. So there are two indexes which will together uniquely identify that particular attribute.

Comment: @Vivz how can I manage two indexes in one checkbox, any example??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use checklist-model, AngularJS directive for list of checkboxes

In Angular one checkbox `<input type="checkbox" ng-model="...">` is linked with one model. But in practice we usually want one model to store array of checked values from several checkboxes. Checklist-model solves that task without additional code in controller. You should play with attributes of `<input type="checkbox">` tag:

- set `checklist-model` instead of ng-model
- set `checklist-value` - what should be picked as array item

[Documentation](https://vitalets.github.io/checklist-model/)

Answer (score 0):

This Because of this function: `vm.disSelectPlayer($index, player)`

I think you have to add index here `<li ng-repeat="player in team.players">` in order to give each player different id or index.

Try This :
 `<li ng-repeat="(key ,player) in team.players">`

and use this Key in the function that you call : 
`vm.disSelectPlayer($index, player , key)`

I hope it is useful :)

Answer (score 0):

This is because on on line #4 you wrote

```
ng-model="vm.newEvent.players[$index].selected".
```

You have used parents object ie players, instead of this you can use

```
ng-model="vm.player.selected".
```

OR

```
ng-model="vm.team.players[$index].selected".
```